# Querying mysql database for records specific to datetime misses some records

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a table which stores information related to user on each visit of certain pages.
I am using Laravel and I'm trying to create a chart based on time (x-axis) and count (y-axis) of visits. since the x-axis is the period, it is divided into smaller periods of time and for each point on x-axis i extract the count of visits from database.
the problem is where i query for each period i get an amount of records which sum of them do not match the count of records for entire period.

the laravel's schema:

```
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
$table->string('id', 32)->primary();
$table->string('user_id', 32)->nullable();
$table->string('relation_id', 32)->nullable();
$table->ipAddress('ip');
$table->string('source', 3);
$table->tinyInteger('type');
$table->timestamp('created_at');
```

the query for the count of records for entire period, for example past month:

```sql
SELECT
  `ip`, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
  `visits`
WHERE
  `created_at` >= '2023-07-08 00:00:00' 
  AND `created_at` <= '2023-08-07 23:59:59'
GROUP BY
  `ip`;
```

returns 67 records in total.

the query for count of records for first point which is a smaller period within the month:

```sql
SELECT
  `ip`, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM`visits` 
WHERE
  `created_at` >= '2023-07-08 00:00:00' 
  AND `created_at` <= '2023-07-13 03:59:59' 
GROUP BY
  `ip`;
```

returns 40 records. count of next points till the end of month are almost the same. so sum of them is far more than 67 total count.

i ran the queries in mysql directly to see and compare each points records against total records and i noted that there are records in each point which are not included in entire periods query result.

any advice on how to get more accurate result?

i appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `BETWEEN`? `whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])` generates `WHERE created_at BETWEEN $from AND $to`.

Comment: yes actually i tried that first. results are the same.

Comment: :facepalm: The same IP may present in both semi-ranges. In this case you count it once in total but twice in partials.  https://dbfiddle.uk/6SsEta-X

Comment: @Akina well thank you for that :facepalm: . you know, i did use laravel's unique('ip') method which returns records unique by ip but what i did not consider is filtering same ip's within each range for the entire range. thanks again.